# Max Energy for Performance

Tags: energy

Not taking into account any supplements like BCAAs, caffeine, etc, how can I best optimize myself for solid energy for 1-1.5 hours of a workout, whether weight training or cardio or a mix of the two?

I understand carbs give energy, simple for quick and complex for more sustainable, but I have a hard time either with timing or digestion.

Any recommendations for how to fuel myself during the day and prepare for a workout based solely on food intake and timing? Especially when the aim is to "cut" and opting to reduce total calories?

Answer (score 1):

There are no simple tricks or special recommendations, as far as I know (excluding supplements like BCAA/Caffeine/etc.)

Try to not be too hungry or too full right before the workout. Stay hydrated during the workout!

You will need to experiment with timing of food, if you are having issues with digestion. Try eating lighter meals an hour or two before the workout.

Feeling a bit hungry is OK, as long as you don't feel lethargic. 
If you are actually trying to cut - you will notice the decrease in energy during workouts. It is normal. You are operating on a lower than usual amount of energy. So, don't beat yourself over it too much. :)